# SQL query, extracting words/ information from a column of Data

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a sql code that takes text from after the first arrow, but stops at a second? (if applicable). Using dbms PostgreSQL.

e.g extracting the information in bold

```
Cat --> Dog 
Park Bench --> Window / Door / House 
Test --> OBJECT 
Train Journey --> Coat -->  ha 64,10 cm (19 Woll)
Elaborate --> All-in-One 
HUH --> Scarf --> Yellow 122
HUH --> Scarf --> Yellow 123
HUH --> Scarf --> Yellow 124
HUH --> Scarf --> Yellow 125
HUH --> Scarf 
Branches --> Wood / Leaf 
Branches --> Scarf 
Branches --> Car 
Two way --> Drawers -->  ha 33,02 cm (13 Woll)
Ordinary --> Table 
Two way --> Drawers -->  ha 49,18 cm (17 Woll)
Two way --> 5-in-2 / Lewisham
Two way --> Drawers -->   ha 33,02 cm (13 Woll)
Ordinary --> London --> Scarf
Ordinary --> ThinHouse 
Window / Door / House --> Hotel --> House - Park
Two way--> London --> Scarf
Two way--> London 
HUH --> Bowl --> Spoon 123
HUH --> Hand --> Stage
Production --> Able --> Now
Window / Door --> Always --> Now
Window / Door --> London 
Window / Door --> Longevity --> Sonstige
Ordinary --> London 
HUH --> HUH Window / Door 
Window / Door --> Longevity -->  ha 45,72 cm (18 Woll)
Ordinary --> London --> Scarf
```

Comment: What kind of request do you try ?

Comment: Are all these `-->` part of the data? Is it always the word after the first `-->` that you want to extract?

Comment: Yes the --> are included in the data. Each line is a cell in the data. Yes the words after the first arrow (but stops at the second arrow) is always what I want to extract

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`split_part()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) function to get that element:

```
select split_part(the_column, '-->', 2)
from your_table;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/7123

Comment: Thank you so much! You are a lifesaver. Spent many hours at work trying to sort this out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some split function with delimiter '-->', below is a split function I use in t-sql:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
    @Text VARCHAR(MAX),
    @Delimiter VARCHAR(100),
    @Index INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @A TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY, V VARCHAR(MAX));
    DECLARE @R VARCHAR(MAX);
    WITH CTE AS
    (
    SELECT 0 A, 1 B
    UNION ALL
    SELECT B, CONVERT(INT,CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @Text, B) + LEN(@Delimiter))
    FROM CTE
    WHERE B > A
    )
    INSERT @A(V)
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@Text,A,CASE WHEN B > LEN(@Delimiter) THEN B-A-LEN(@Delimiter) ELSE LEN(@Text) - A + 1 END) VALUE      
    FROM CTE WHERE A >0

    SELECT      @R
    =           V
    FROM        @A
    WHERE       ID = @Index + 1
    RETURN      @R
END
GO
```

You should specify the index which in your case is 1

```
SELECT SPLIT(myField,'-->',1) FROM myTable
```

Comment: Very product specific answer, to a question with no dbms specified.

Comment: Thank you for your comment shukri gashi.

Apologies for not including a dbms. I am needing the code for dbms PostgreSQL

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was t-sql.